# Access VBA: combine GetRows with bookmark

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a small dataset with a maintable and one table being dependent on the maintable. One record in the main table can have multiple related records in the subtable.

I also created a form (maintable) with a subform (subtable).

Afterwards, I created two recordsetclones based on the form and the subform respectively.

Adding the bookmark method also allows me to use data from the record that is actually active in the form. The problem is: the bookmark only applies to the mainform.

I used GetRows to create an array variable to be filled with the records from the subform. The array is filled, but with all records from the subtable. I only want those records which are currently shown on the subform.

I'm using a DAO recordset.

How can I fix this?

My code so far:

```
Sub FillMail()

    Dim rstMail As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rstIsin As DAO.Recordset

    Dim db As Database
    Dim isinarray As Variant

    Set rstMail = Forms!Transfert.RecordsetClone
    Set rstIsin = Forms!TFT_ISIN_DatasheetSub2.RecordsetClone
    Set db = CurrentDb

    rstMail.Bookmark = Forms!Transfert.Bookmark
    rstIsin.Bookmark = Forms!TFT_ISIN_DatasheetSub2.Bookmark

    isinarray = rstIsin.GetRows

    MsgBox isinarray(2, 0)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the subform `TFT_ISIN_DatasheetSub2` is in a subform control under the main form `Transfert`, link the Master and Child fields in the sub form control, and change:

```
Set rstIsin = Forms!TFT_ISIN_DatasheetSub2.RecordsetClone
```

to:

```
Set rstIsin = Forms!Transfert!subTFT_ISIN.RecordsetClone
```

This assumes your subform control is named `subTFT_ISIN`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I hadn't yet created a subform. I did it now like you suggested (subform based on the subtable). I also adapted the code like you suggested. However, Set rstIsin = Forms!Transfert!subTFT_ISIN.RecordsetClone is not working. Set rstIsin = Forms!subTFT_ISIN.RecordsetClone does fine. However, when doing this, I still get in my array all the values of the subtable and not just those values which are in in subform for the current record.

Comment: Did you setup the Master and Child fields in the SubForm control on the parent form?